# Find out what created the window?

Tags: debugging, window

dap mode keeps creating unwanted window, I'd like to prevent it but can't find a way

I can think of setting a breakpoint on window-creation.
But there seems to be a lot of those split window functions..

I was wondering if `(view-lossage)` would show, but it just shows cmds I invoked..

Comment: You *might* be able to break when entering `display-buffer` to display the buffer of interest. Then a backtrace will give you the call chain.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for the idea